# Laravel: No data found

Tags: laravel

Okay so i am trying to display data on my page, but when i run my code my message appears saying 'no posts found' (this is coded in if there isn't any posts) although i have 4 pieces of data in my database that should be displaying. Im a bit confused at why my posts are not appearing:

Welcome.blade.php

```
@if(isset($postings) && count($postings) > 1)
 @foreach($postings as $post)
    <h2><a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h2>
 @endforeach
   @else
      </p>no posts found</p>
    @endif
```

HomeController.php

```
    public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}

public function index1()
{
    $postings = Post::all();
    return view('Pages.welcome', compact('postings'));
}
```

Web.api

```
**Route::get('/', 'PageController@index');
Route::get('/welcome1', 'HomeController@index1');**
Route::get('/services', 'PageController@services');
Route::get('/register', 'PageController@register');
Route::get('/Create', 'PageController@Create');
Route::get('/search', 'PageController@search');
Route::get('/payment', 'PageController@Payment');

Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::resource('search', 'SearchController');
Route::resource('reviews', 'ReviewsController');
**Route::resource('postings', 'HomeController');**
```

Comment: name table post ?

Comment: what do you mean by 'name table post'

Comment: Did you notice in your condition count() > 1. this passes only if there are more posts than 1, starting 2. So are you sure there are more than 1 posts in the database. And i think what you want is count() > 0

Comment: Hi there are defiantly more than 4 posts in my database, even when i change it to  0 still there are no posts appearing.

Comment: Can you show your model code? plus table screenshot? I can't see any mistake in your code as you said you've 4 records in the post table. can you share a screenshot of the table + model code?

Comment: share your routes also ? and `home.blade.php` ?

Comment: see edited code with my routes

Comment: The code is correct, are you using /welcome1 url? or /postings. Because your /postings point to HomeController@index function which won't return any post.
Also, if possible post output of php artisan route:list

Comment: Thats the thing i didnt know which function to use. Are you saying use the  **Route::resource('postings', 'HomeController');**

Comment: move the lines inside index1 function to index function thats all. You should be able to access data at /postings url

Comment: public function index()
    {
        $postings = Post::all();
        return view('Pages.welcome', compact('postings'));

    }  like this >

Comment: @SahilJain so i did that and i had no luck still getting the same problem

Comment: Do you have code on github?

Comment: Hi Sahil, its not a problem no more, i managed to solve it, i simply created a new controller and in my routes i simply did Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
@forelse ($postings as $post)
    <h2><a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h2>
@empty
   </p>no posts found</p>
@endforelse
```